# how to use DAX query on relational Database

Tags: sql-server, database, dax

I have a relational data base on SqlServer 2014,
We need ,professional user  to do some statistical calculation (like Excel functions) on data , I found that DAX functions cover our user requirement.
But, I do not know if it is possible?!
Or, if there is another option for my requirement?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is possible. You can import your database to Power Pivot and create a model to perform statistical operations. You should consider the amount of data you want to import and permission and security issues though. Maybe a SSAS Tabular Instance to hold your model could be better.

Comment: tanx @ alejandro zuleta , I want to do statistical operation on cuurent data , can I import database to Power Pivot and execute DAX Query on data? my server code c#.net and I want to connect to Power Pivot.

Comment: Yes, once you create a Power Pivot model based on the imported database, you can execute DAX queries to analyze the data.